# How to emit an event as object value in a class?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an event and its value like this:

```
new ExampleClass({
 onExampleEvent: (val) => {
    console.log(val)
  }
})
```

But this doesn't works.

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 121;
    console.log(this.value)
    
    let i = 0;
    
    setInterval(() => {
      i++;
      this.onExampleEvent(i)
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  onExampleEvent(val) {
    return val
  }
}

new Example({
  // this event should be triggered every second
  onExampleEvent: (val) => {
    console.log(val)
  }
})
```

How to emit an event like this?

Comment: The method `onExampleEvent` only returns the argument. `this.onExampleEvent(i)` discards this return value, as there’s nowhere the value is returned _to_. You construct `Example` with an argument of an object with an `onExampleEvent` property, but your constructor doesn’t accept any arguments, so nothing happens with this object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the event as a parameter. You must use it as a parameter in the constructor and call it from there.

```js
class Example {
  constructor(options) {
    this.value = 121;
    console.log(this.value)

    let i = 0;
    
    setInterval(() => {
      i++;
      options.onExampleEvent(i)
    }, 1000)
  }
}

new Example({
  // this event should be triggered every second
  onExampleEvent: (val) => {
    console.log(val)
  }
})
```

And if you don't want to call the event inside the constructor.

```js
class Example {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.someFunction();
  }

  someFunction() {
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      i++;
      this.options.onExampleEvent(i);
    }, 1000)
  }
}

new Example({
  // this event should be triggered every second
  onExampleEvent: (val) => {
    console.log(val)
  }
})
```

Comment: if I want to emit in a class function, not in constructor, what should I do? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljs8kmbe/

Comment: in that case, you need to store the options, you're receiving as a property of the Example class. Then you can call `this.options.onExampleEvent(parameter)` in a function